# Configuring TDS manually with Encryption DB2

Tags: db2

When I upgrade my Simple DB2 v10.5.0.0 with Fix pack for Encryption DB2,it changes the db2level from 10.5.0.0 to 10.5.0.3.

And when I tune my DB2 with TDS. I first create an instance then set admin password and when I run command `"/opt/IBM/ldap/V6.3/sbin/idscfgdb -n -I <instance name> -a <instance name> -w <password> -t <ids database name> -l /home/<instance name>"`, for create Database it failed with error

```
GLPCTL026I Creating database: 'db2ldap'.
GLPCTL028E Failed to create database: 'db2ldap'. The failure might have occurred because the system was not set up correctly before using the tool.
GLPCTL011I Stopping database manager for the database instance: 'db2inst1'.
```

Comment: How is this related to Chef?

Comment: want to do  silent installation of TDS via cookbook...Currently,doing itmanually .With simple Db2 it is working.

Comment: Whatever you are doing manually, do that with Chef.

Comment: If it not working manually ..how comes with chef?

Comment: Find your DB2 instance's db2diag.log, and inspect it. The real error will most likely be found in there.